# Any group can be regarded as an operator group with empty operator domain.

Tags: group-theory

Hi: This is the definition of operator group given in the book I am studying:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

The author says: if $\Omega$ is the empty set, then an $\Omega$-group is just a group. I ask: an element of $G\times \emptyset$ is an ordered pair. How do I write $g\in G$ as an ordered pair in $G\times \emptyset$? I never considered the cartesian product of two sets when one of the sets is empty.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: The Cartesian product of the empty set with any set $A$ is empty. Suppose otherwise. Then there exists an element $\alpha\in A\times \emptyset$, which can be written component-wise as $\alpha=(a,e)$ for some $a\in A$ and some $e\in \emptyset$. But $\emptyset$ has no elements.

Comment: Derek Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, 2nd edition, New York, 1966. There is a similar definition and the same assertion in Rotman, An introduction to Group Theory, 4th edition.

Comment: ERRATA: where it says 1966 it should say 1996.

Comment: There is only one function $\alpha$ from the empty set into $G$: The empty set, which is a subset of $\emptyset \times G$. I have to prove that something is an endomorphism of $G$ for each $\omega\in \Omega$. In what way could this be false? Only if there were an $\omega\in \Omega$ such that  $g\mapsto g^\omega$ is not an endomorphism of $G$. But there is no $\omega \in \Omega$ because $\Omega$ is empty. So, the assertion is true. Is this correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me, @stf91.